# Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. [$aH =Hb$]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. If for each $a \in G$, there exists $b \in G$ such that $aH = Hb$, then prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $aH=Hb$ then $a\in Hb$ so $a=hb$ then $Hb=H(hb)=Ha$. Hence, $aH=Ha$.